# Help me understand how action is applied on the example given:

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $\operatorname{Sym}(x)$ be the symetric group and then $\operatorname{Sym}(2)=\{id,(1,2)\}$. Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$. (This might be wrong as i think this set must only contain $1$ and $2$ as elements.)

Define the function $f:\operatorname{Sym}(2)\times X\to X$, where $f(x,y)=x\circ y$ and $\circ$ is the composition of maps.

So therefore $f:\{(id,1),(id,2),(id,3),((1,2),1),((1,2),2),((1,2),3)\}\to\{1,2,3\}$.

> The question now it is how can I apply an action on an element of the domain. So for example $f((1,2),2)=(1,2)\circ 2=$?

This has been taken from lecture notes as being an example written as: $S_n$ acts on $\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ via application of each map.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, $\operatorname{Sym}(2)$ acts on $X$ via $f$ by defining $f: \operatorname{Sym}(2)\times X\to X$ by $(\alpha, x)\mapsto \alpha\circ x$; that is, $f(\alpha, x)=\alpha\circ x\stackrel{\operatorname{Def}}{=}\alpha(x)$, where $\alpha(x)$ is $\alpha$ evaluated at $x\in X$.

It follows that here $X$ can be any set with $\{1,2\}\subseteq X$.

Using your example, $f((12), 2)=(12)\circ 2\stackrel{\operatorname{Def}}{=}(12)(2)=1$.

*NB:* Here $\stackrel{\operatorname{Def}}{=}$ means "is, by definition, equal to".

Comment: I m sorry but how did you get (12)(2)=1? I m a bit confuse

Comment: Is it clear now, @BurLeXyOOnuTz?

Comment: Not really, sorry. When you do (12) ∘ 2 I don't really understand what you are following at that bit. I mean what sort of operation you do.

Comment: The notation $(12)\circ 2$ means "$(12)$ of $2$" because, remember, $(12)$ is a bijection on $\{1,2\}$; thus "$(12)\circ 2$" is synonymous with "$(12)$ evaluated at $2$", which is, in turn, synonymous with "$(12)(2)$", *i.e.*, $1$. Is that any better, @BurLeXyOOnuTz?

Comment: Is it the fact that 2↦1 in (12)?

Comment: Precisely, @BurLeXyOOnuTz.

Comment: Say I had (123) in the domain and G was a group. So if I was having f((123),1), would that be equal to 2?

Comment: Exactly, @BurLeXyOOnuTz; I think you've got it. Don't forget to upvote & accept my answer!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness

Comment: You're welcome, @BurLeXyOOnuTz.

Comment: I would like to ask you also if the second element passed in to f from f((1,2),2) is a permutation or just a simple number, or how is it called if is not either of those because I m not sure if I ever seen it before.

Comment: The second argument of $f$ in $f(\alpha, x)$ is $x\in \{1,2\}$, so is a number. Does that answer your question, @BurLeXyOOnuTz?

Comment: Is it not the second element the id? as 2 →2 , 1→1 and 3→3 or is it just a simple number passed to see where it goes by applying (1,2)?

Comment: It's the argument of the function $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ can be, in your example, $(12)$ or the identity, @BurLeXyOOnuTz; I suggest you ask a separate question on MSE if the one you asked in the original post above has been answered.